# No data passed in submit method of Redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I want to send the input values to the api.
I used the code from below link, to get the input values in the submit method, but though the submit method gets called, the variable is empty.

[How to handle redux form submitted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477712/how-to-handle-redux-form-submitted-data)

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import ContactForm from "./ContactForm";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import rootReducers from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ContactForm />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as formReducer } from "redux-form";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer
});
export default rootReducer;
```

ContactForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { reduxForm } from "redux-form";

class ContactForm extends Component {
  submit(formValues) {
    console.log(formValues);
  }
  render() {
    const {
      fields: { firstName, lastName, email },
      handleSubmit
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}>
        <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" {...firstName} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" {...lastName} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" {...email} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ContactForm = reduxForm({
  form: "contact",
  fields: ["firstName", "lastName", "email"]
})(ContactForm);

export default ContactForm;
```

I am getting formValues as empty. Could anyone please help me with it?

Comment: It is unclear to me what the `handleSubmit` function is doing. It takes in `this.submit`, but what does it do with it? Can you please share the code for `handleSubmit`

Comment: did you pass form reducer to your root reducer?

Comment: @TrevorJohnson : There is no implementation for handleSubmit. You may check here :  https://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/getting-started?_k=8q7qyo

Comment: @sathishkumar : If you see my above code, you would notice :
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer
});

Comment: Then it looks like you don’t need to pass in your own function to handleSubmit. Look at the example there closely. They just specify handleSubmit as the function to run when the onSubmit event occurs.

Comment: @TrevorJohnson : I tried that. Got this error:
You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the example was for version 5.3.1 of Redux-form, while I had installed 8.1.0 version.
Below is the working code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";

const submit = values => {
  console.log(values);
};

class ContactForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
        <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <Field name="lastName" component="input" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <Field name="email" component="input" type="email" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "contact"
})(ContactForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use  instead of  inside the form, to connect your input data with redux store.

https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/submitvalidation/